# About Angular2 "garbage collection"

Tags: javascript, angular

This question is not about a problem, but for arranging some things inside my mind about how Angular2 works.

I'm building an app that loads a grid of components when the user selects the corresponding option. Some of the grids have more than 300 components, and each component is a listbox that displays a list of objects from a JSON variable.

So, for example, when the user clicks on "Garage 1", the application makes an API call to get a JSON object and loops through it to generate every listbox. When the user selects another garage, we repeat the operation: call to the API and regenerate the listboxes.

I don't delete or unset the used variables through different calls (I always use the same), so I'm afraid that the application is taking up more and more memory on each call.

So my question is: is this a proper way of programming or should I unset the variables somehow before making the API calls? Does Angular2/4 have any "garbage collector" like Java?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Angular has "grabage collection" like Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection

Comment: first of all, angular is JavaScript. all the codes are bundled together to produce js code